# Eclipse Debugging- out of sync Issue

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging a web app in Eclipse IDE (Helios release Build Id 20100617-1415). The app runs on LifeRay-tomcat bundle via Eclipse plugin (running server from within Eclipse). I start LifeRay-tomcat server in Debug mode. I'm doing hot deployment- copying .class files to webapps//WEB-INF/classes folder. I run a windows batch script for copying any changed bytecode to liferay-tomcat directory. When the bytecode gets copies, I see a message in debug console saying "may be out of sync" and the moment I refresh the web page and control jumps on the line number, my debugger thread icon changed to red and the warning message now reads "out of sync". Even if I clear all breakpoints, I get this message and new code is no longer debuggable; every time I need to restart the server.

Any suggestion on this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse framework has a complex workspace management. You said that are using a script for copying the class, if your script is not a eclipse feature it will breaks the workspace resource, so you will cannot debug.

Try to use only eclipse features for doing the debug.

Comment: Well, the script is just one way to move new byte code. Even if I manually copy-paste the .class file(s), I see the debugger going out of sync.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? The eclipse framework will handle this. Configure your server on preferences, and use "Debug as" on the server configuration. All "manual" work should be done by eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

I've created an Eclipse Java Builder which points to a .bat file to copy the new byte code. So, I guess it's an Eclipse feature. That said, I don't think there's any issue with the script or the way it's used. Even if I manually copy-paste the changed .class files, I get out of sync issue resulting in restarting the container.